# Simultaneously fitting to data to estimate a common parameter with NaN data in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, missing-data

I have data (y) measured in over 4 time points (t), for three concentrations (c).
So data will be like:

> Under c1: y11,y12,y13,y14 (measured at the 4 time points)
>
> Under  c2:y21,y12,y23,y24
>
> under c3:  y31,y32,y33,y34

What I am trying to do is to estimate two parameters `c` and `d` by fitting simultaneously to all these data measures at diffferent concnetrations.
However, some of these values are NaNs. So, for example,

> Under  c2:y21,y12,NaN,NaN
>
> under c3:  y31,y32,y33,NaN

here is the Matlab code that I have written.

```
%C contains the different concentration values (c1,c2,c3)
[fittedVals,errorVals]=lsqcurvefit(@(xEstimate,thours)model(xEstimate,t,C),initial,t,y,lb,ub);

function output= model(xEstimate,t,C)

intVals=repmat(10^5,3,1);%initial value of the ODE system

[~,values] = ode45(@(t,y)Equations(t,y,C),t,intVals);

function s=Equations(~,y,para)

    a=0.25;
    b=-0.1;
    k=xEstimate(1);
    d=xEstimate(2);
    concentration=para;%different concentrations

    s=zeros(3,1);
    s(1)=a*y(1)-y(1)*(((a-b)*(concentration(1)/k).^d)/((concentration(1)/k).^d-(b/(a)))); 
    s(2)=a*y(2)-y(2)*(((a-b)*(concentration(2)/k).^d)/((concentration(2)/k).^d-(b/(a)))); 
    s(3)=a*y(3)-y(3)*(((a-b)*(concentration(3)/k).^d)/((concentration(3)/k).^d-(b/(a)))); 



   end

output=values;
end
```

This code works when data is not NaN but, with missing data, it gives an error as:

> Objective function is returning undefined values at initial point.
>   lsqcurvefit cannot continue.

What can I do here to solve this problem? Should I input time and y data as cell arrays?
If so I don't quite understand how to change the code to work with cell arrays.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This depends entirely on how *you* expect to fit to NaN... do you want to omit those parts of your curve? Do you want to interpolate/extrapolate from the non-NaN values?

Comment: @Wolfie I want to omit these from the curve. I do not want to use these in the estimation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is use [`lsqnonlin`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html) instead of `lsqcurvefit`. This allows you to have more flexibility in the error vector you want to minimize.

You can determine the error for each measurement per concentration, and then combine these to a large error vector which you want to minimize. A simple example is e.g. a model of a sine, with varying amplitude, frequency and phase. Say we know the phase, and want to find the amplitude and frequency.

The model is:

```
function y = model(t, A, w, phi)
    y = A.*sin(w.*t+phi); 
end
```

The error function for the fitting process takes the measured data, and known parameters. Determine the `y_estimated` for a certain parameter set (given by `lsqnonlin`), and determine the error with the measured values `y_meas`. Do this for all the different concentrations, and combine in one error vector. Since some values in `y_meas` are NaN, and you want to omit them, remove them from the error vector.

```
function err = errorFun(params, y_meas, t, phi)

    % get w and phi from params
    A = params(1:3);
    w = params(4:6);

    % simulate model with params to estimate
    yest = model(t, A, w, phi);

    % determine error vector
    err = y_meas-yest; 
    err = err(:);           % make one vector
    err(isnan(err)) = [];   % remove NaNs
end
```

Example:

```
t = 0:0.5:4*pi;
A = rand(3,1);
w =  rand(3,1);
phi = rand(3,1);

y_true = A.*sin(w.*t+phi); % three sinusoids

% measured data
y_meas = y_true;
y_meas(randi([1 numel(y_meas)], 10,1)) = NaN; % set some values to NaN

% optimize
% p = [A;w];
p0 = [A;w;]+0.1; % small deviation from initial parameters, for the example
[p_estimated,a] = lsqnonlin(@(p) errorFun(p,y_meas,t,phi), p0); 

A_est = p_estimated(1:3);
w_est = p_estimated(4:6);

disp([A A_est w w_est])
```